# Reusing SQL server Database Connections With Azure Functions Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, azure-functions

I cannot find clear information on how to manage SQL server database connections from an Azure function written in Javascript.

I am using a connection pool code -

```
const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
const poolConnect = pool.connect();

pool.on('error', err => {
    // ... error handler
})
```

and I am using the **poolConnect** object from the function which is executing the query

```
export const selectQuery = function() {
  const connectionPool = await mssqlDBPoolConnect;
  const request = connectionPool.request();
  await request.query('select query');
}
```

So how can I use the same connection pool across all azure functions.

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click on the mark option beside the reply to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.), see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two folder named config and toolkit under your root path. Put your `db.js` in `config` folder, and create a sql helper class to export a function named `sqltools.js` in toolkit folder.

So you could use the same connection pool by calling `sqltools` in your function's code. This step help you to reduce using the same code in every function.

[image]

Try use the `db.js` code below:

```
const sql = require('mssql')
const config = {
    user: 'yourusername',
    password: 'yourpassword',
    server: 'yoursqlserver.database.windows.net', // You can use 'localhost\\instance' to connect to named instance. Do not use TCP.
    database: 'yourdb',
    "options": {
        "encrypt": true,
        "enableArithAbort": true
    }
}

const poolPromise = new sql.ConnectionPool(config)
  .connect()
  .then(pool => {
    console.log('Connected to MSSQL')
    return pool
  })
  .catch(err => console.log('Database Connection Failed! Bad Config: ', err))

module.exports = {
  sql, poolPromise
}
```

The `sqltools.js` class:

```
const { poolPromise } = require('../config/db')

module.exports.sqltools = {
    ExecSqlQuery : async function(arg){
        const pool = await poolPromise
        //SELECT *FROM SYSOBJECTS WHERE xtype = \'U\'
        var result=null;
        try {
            result = await pool.request()
            .query(arg)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
        } 
        return result;
    },
    ExecProce : function (arg2, arg3, arg4){
        console.log(arg2,arg3,arg4);
    }
}
```

## Here is my HttpTrigger1 `index.js` code, call `ExecSqlQuery` to exec `sqlstrings`:

```
const { sqltools } = require('../toolkit/sqltools');

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
    var result=null;
    try {
        // call ExecSqlQuery func
        result = await sqltools.ExecSqlQuery('SELECT *FROM SYSOBJECTS WHERE xtype = \'U\'');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    } 
    
    const responseMessage ="Func 1 Result : TableName= " + result.recordset[0].name;

    context.res = {
        // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
        body: responseMessage
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Its working, just want to clarify one thing, will all my azure functions will use the same connection every time. I don't want to create the new connection every time for each azure function

Comment: My answer is just a sample code, you need to improve the content in db.js by yourself and export a sqlclient. When connecting to the database, pay attention to exception handling and remember to dispose connect. Refer to this: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/03/11/node-sql-server